# Celery time limit setting by queue

Tags: python, celery

I have a project using Celery and originally implementing one unique queue, which could cause some trouble.

So I want to implement several queues (which is done and works), but I would like to set different soft time limitd per queue. Actually the only things I found is [time_limit](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits) as global setting for Celery, or setting it every time I decorate a task. First is a too generic solution, the second is not enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

During you queue definition you can set a time to live `x-message-ttl` on it.

```
 Queue('test_queue', Exchange('default'), routing_key='test_queue', queue_arguments={'x-message-ttl': 86400000})
```